# FIND MAXIMUM DEPTNO USING FUNCTION

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Using PLSQL I have to find the  max DEPTNO from DEPT TABLE using Functions AND This Function will return the max deptno from DEPT TABLE when called.
MY PROBLEM IS HOW can I do this without leaving the arguments EMPTY.

My task is this: create a PL/SQL function that will return the greatest (maximum) `deptno` from the `dept` table when called. Name this function as `f_find_maxdept`. Write an anonymous block to test this function.

My code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_find_maxdept()return number is 
max_deptno dept.deptno%TYPE;
begin
    select max(deptno) into max_dept from dept;
    return max_dept;
end f_find_maxdept;
```

Comment: It depends on what parameter you need.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Please edit your post to use proper upper- and lower-case. ALL CAPS comes across as shouting.

Comment: You can always add a dummy parameter...

Comment: The task, as you have written it in your question, does not state that the function requires a parameter. Why do you think it does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your function requires no parameters then you should omit the parentheses

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_find_maxdept return number ...
```

Comment: that's exactly what i was trying to find.

Answer (score 1):

Both the function you are creating and the database table that you query in that function, need to be in the same schema.

From the Oracle documentation for CREATE FUNCTION statement:

> To create or replace a function in your own schema, you must have the CREATE PROCEDURE system privilege. To create or replace a function in another user's schema, you must have the CREATE ANY PROCEDURE system privilege.

I'm guessing that table DEPT is in the SCOTT schema and you are trying to create a function in your schema.

Assuming that you have the CREATE ANY PROCEDURE system privilege, you could write the following SQL to create the function:

```sql
create or replace function SCOTT.F_FIND_MAXDEPT
  return number
is
  MAX_DEPTNO  SCOTT.DEPTS.DEPTNO%type;
begin
  select max(DEPTNO)
    into MAX_DEPTNO
    from SCOTT.DEPTS;
  return MAX_DEPTNO;
end;
```

Alternatively, you could make a copy of the DEPTS table in your schema.

```sql
create table DEPTS as select * from SCOTT.DEPTS;
```

Then you would create the function like so:

```sql
create or replace function F_FIND_MAXDEPT
  return number
is
  MAX_DEPTNO  DEPTS.DEPTNO%type;
begin
  select max(DEPTNO)
    into MAX_DEPTNO
    from DEPTS;
  return MAX_DEPTNO;
end;
```

And an anonymous PL/SQL block to test the function would be (assuming you created the DEPTS table in your schema):

```sql
declare
  MAX_DEPT  DEPTS.DEPTNO%type;
begin
  MAX_DEPT := F_FIND_MAXDEPT;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(MAX_DEPT);
end;
```